# Are dream related questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Our site is countering some questions which are not yet decided as on-topic.

Recently, our site got this post:

- [What is the meaning of seeing Devi Durga in dream for non-Hindu?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/2553/93)

The above question is asking for explanation of a dream.

This seems to be on-topic to me because if we visit any temple, the pundits there explains the dream. but I am not sure whether this is mentioned in any scriptures.

So, the question is:

Are dream related questions on-topic? if yes, to which extent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that discussing about dreams should be considered off topic, this is not even a topic which has a wider scope, i.e we cannot possibly answer a question asking about dreams.

For example, if a user asks a question like "Did lord Krishna dreamt about ..." is a different thing, but asking something like "Yesterday I saw lord Vishnu in dreams, what could be the reason?" or "I saw a dream where I became a millionaire, so will that come true?" etc has no answers.

So questions like this should be ignored and should be closed voted, because I don't see any reason why we should be asking the meaning behind our dreams as they vary from person to person.

Short Answer : **Off-Topic**

Comment: I think questions where a user asks us to interpet their dream should probably be off-topic, but more general questions like "What do dreams about Vishnu mean according to Hinduism?" are certainly within the scope of the site, because Hindu scripture does discuss this sort of question.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan So does scriptures answers us for every god we see in our dreams? Because we will get tons of those later, also, its a cross origin question, some may find offensive, while some may not..

Comment: I agree the particular question that raised this issue is probably not a good question for the site.  But questions that ask about dreams in more broad strokes should be acceptable.

Comment: And no, I don't think Hindu scripture provides detail on what seeing each god means.  It does provide detail, though, on broader questions, like what seeing a god at all means, what seeing objects like fire means, where dreams come from, what the nature of nightmares is, etc.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan yea, seeing something peculiar is acceptable but not the general ones, I agree with you on that point

Comment: It's not an issue of peculiar dreams vs normal dreams, it's about narrow questions about dreams vs broader questions.  Scriptures mostly address the broader questions.  For instance, if you ask "I dreamt I ate two mangos and three oranges", then scripture doesn't really address how to interpret that.  But if you ask "What is the significance of eating within dreams?" that might have an answer.

Comment: Anyways I've closed that question for now, also cleaning up the site, deleted non credited copied answers, junk comments etc..

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan please share your thoughts as an answer here instead of comments. :)

Comment: @Mr_Green his thoughts are no different from mine

Comment: @Mr.Alien So are questions like "What do dreams about gods mean according to Hinduism?", "What is the meaning of seeing a snake in dreams?" are off-topic?

Comment: @Mr_Green about first, yes, about second, dicey.

Comment: I asked it because it wasn't highlighted in your post as Keshav mentioned in comments. please update your post to highlight the same. (_or maybe I didn't get the same point from your post_).