# What's the reason one question got put on hold and other one wasn't?

Tags: discussion

[Lord shiva in my dreams](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31907/lord-shiva-in-my-dreams)

This was put on hold as off topic.

['Dream' of Lord Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21921/dream-of-lord-shiva)

This question, is on similar grounds.

I am trying to understand why the first one is off topic but second one is not. Any inputs?

Comment: [The comment on the second question by Turiyanath](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21921/dream-of-lord-shiva#comment63143_21921) might give a hint: generalized question. The first question seems too specific to be helpful for the asker only, while Stack Exchange is meant for building a Q&A database that helps many people, not only a single person (hence the close reason).

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer** : [Questions asking for dream analysis are off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/262/5212).

**Long answer** :

If you look at the [revisions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/21921/revisions) of ['Dream' of Lord Shiva](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21921/5212), you will understand that the question has been changed a lot removing all the details of dream and asking its analysis. It was edited to make a general question so that there won't be any questions further.

Now the question which put on hold recently has a question what does a dream mean. There can be thousands of dreams to many users and each and every one will give different interpretations. [You may get a question like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIHdl.jpg) So, you don't know which one is correct and follow. Moreover, you never know if the details are accurate. These reflect the ideas of the person who saw the dream. As Andrew.T says [in the comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1533/whats-the-reason-one-question-got-put-on-hold-and-other-one-wasnt#comment6825_1533) under your question, they are *only* helpful to the user who asks the question. These questions will not be helpful to others who read and the answer will not be satisfying and will rise to speculations.

This is the reason [dream related questions are made off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/262/5212) a long ago.

To reflect this, the tag wiki of the [dream](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dream) says the following:

> **This tag can be used for general questions about dreams**. A dream is a succession of images, ideas, emotions, and sensations that usually occurs involuntarily in the mind during certain stages of sleep. **Note that analysis of a specific dream is off-topic**.

So, questions which ask for general dream questions are within our scope but which asks for analysis are off-topic even if there is mention of it in the scriptures. Because there are different circumstances a dream is seen and depends on person to person.

Comment: 'This is the reason dream related questions are made off-topic a long ago.' - why isn't [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/260) an FAQ then? How do you know it's being enforced?

Comment: @sv. Many questions with such details were closed immediately either by a moderator or by users. Moreover, I discussed with a mod about a question which was closed like that. That is how I came to know. Perhaps it is not a frequently asked question, that is why it is not added faq.